# Separating and printing out the even and odd random numbers

Tags: c++, random

I have generated 100 random numbers, where I have to shorted out equal even and odd numbers of the random numbers. All even or odd numbers can not be repetitive.

For example I will create 100 random numbers

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <cstdlib>    

int main()
{
  for (int i=1; i <=100; ++i){

      //double p = rand();
      std::cout <<"random number is :" << rand()<<std::endl;


  }


}
```

Since I don't know if the even and odd numbers are same in the list from the 100 random numbers, I want to pick minimum number of pair even and odd numbers. I also will like to know what the total odd and even numbers are generated separately. One note is that, if for an example, any even or odd number get printed out multiple times, I want to consider that as a one.

For example. Let's assume we have 60 even and 40 odd numbers from the printed random numbers. And also from the 60 even numbers 10 even numbers are repetitive. So I would consider the different event numbers are 50. The printed out numbers would be first 20 even numbers and first 20 odd numbers.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to learn How I can filter out the even and odd numbers from the for loop of random generator.

UPDATE:

My goal is to find even and odd numbers from the generated random numbers. When I short out the even and odd numbers, all the even and odd numbers will be different. Which means, if I found even number 2 printed out  5 times, I would still consider that one. In this way I want to find the minimum number of even and odd numbers.

Lets have an example:

the generated print out is: {1,2,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,3,2,4,6,10}

From the list the even and odd numbers would be:

even = {2,4,6,8}
odd = {1,3,5,9}

If you looked  carefully, I excluded 10 from the even shorting. The reason is that, If i added 10 in the even list, I would have more even than odd.

Comment: `int r = rand(); if (r % 2 == 0) /* it's even */ else /* it's odd */` Or, if you want a bit test `if (r & 1) /* it's odd */ else /* it's even */`

Comment: *"How I can filter out the even and odd numbers from the for loop of random generator."* - are you asking how to *store* numbers in some sort of container rather than letting the rot at the end of each loop ?

Comment: Since it's C++ I would also recommend to use the C++ random num ber generator facility. You can find an example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution. In general, avoid headers starting with "c".

Comment: Two `std::unordered_set` objects if you don't care about number of instances, `std::unordered_map` objects if you do.

Comment: Take a look at std::sort and std::uniq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you explained in your example.

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 6, 10};
  std::set<int> even, odd;

  // sort the numbers into even and odd sets
  for (auto const& n : numbers)
  {
    if (n % 2 == 0)
      even.insert(n);
    else
      odd.insert(n);
  }

  // figure out which set is smaller
  int min = std::min(even.size(), odd.size());

  // print out the evens
  std::cout << "even = ";
  auto it = even.begin();
  for(int i = 0; i < min; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << *(it++) << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // print out the odds
  std::cout << "odd  = ";
  it = odd.begin();
  for(int i = 0; i < min; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << *(it++) << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::unorderd_set` to create odd set and even set

to check number is odd = (num&1) will be 1 for odd and 0 for even

```cpp
std::unordered_set<int> set_odd;
std::unordered_set<int> set_even;
for (int num : nums) {
  if (num & 1) set_odd.insert(num);
  else set_even.insert(even);
}
```

Comment: you declared the sets inside the loop. you probably meant to do that before.

Comment: sorry typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you only want **pairs** of random numbers (pair as in collection of 2-integers, one even, one odd, not `std::pair`), you need a way to generate the numbers, provide storage for the pairs, and keep track of the number of odds generated and number of evens generated and a way to associate the pairs of numbers generated.

To generate the random numbers [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) provides random number generation for int from your choice of random number engines such as the [std::mersenne_twister_engine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine). You can generate a number within a [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) simply by declaring the device, seeding the generator with the device and then creating a distribution between a *min* and *max* of your choice.

To setup and generate random numbers within the positive range of `int` you could do:

```
...
#include <random>

#define NMAX std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
...
    std::random_device rd;    /* delcare the randon number generator device */
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());   /* standard mrsene_twister engine seeded w/rd */
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, NMAX); /* create disribution */
```

And to request a number from the distribution, simply:

```
        int r = dist(rd);                       /* generate rand */
```

How to store the pairs generated depends on how you coordinate adding the even and odd numbers generated to coordinate storing pairs of numbers together. You can use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` or simply use an even and odd `std::vector<int>`. Using the latter allows you to fill an vector of evens and a vector of odds and then simply output the lesser `.size()` of the two to capture the pairs of even-odd generated out of our 100 random integers.

For example:

```
#define MAXRAND 100
...
    std::vector<int> even, odd;
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXRAND; i++) {         /* loop MAXRAND times */
        int r = dist(rd);                       /* generate rand */
        if (r % 2 == 0)                         /* if even */
            even.push_back(r);                  /* add to even vector */
        else    /* odd number */
            odd.push_back(r);                   /* add to odd vector */
    }
```

That way you can specify to generate 100 random numbers and you end up with however many even-odd pairs were generated out of those 100 random numbers -- which sounds like what you were asking.

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

#define NMAX std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
#define MAXRAND 100

int main (void) {

    std::vector<int> even, odd;
    std::random_device rd;    /* delcare the randon number generator device */
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());   /* standard mrsene_twister engine seeded w/rd */
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, NMAX); /* create disribution */
    size_t limit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXRAND; i++) {         /* loop MAXRAND times */
        int r = dist(rd);                       /* generate rand */
        if (r % 2 == 0)                         /* if even */
            even.push_back(r);                  /* add to even vector */
        else    /* odd number */
            odd.push_back(r);                   /* add to odd vector */
    }
    /* output results */
    limit = (even.size() > odd.size()) ? odd.size() : even.size();
    std::cout << limit << " even-odd pairs (0 - " << NMAX << ")\n\n";
    for (size_t p = 0; p < limit; p++)
        std::cout << std::setw(12) << even.at(p) << 
                    "  " << odd.at(p) << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running you will generally generate between 40-50 pairs of numbers -- the random distributions being fairly good, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/evenoddpairs
48 even-odd pairs (0 - 2147483647)

  1513290664  712950177
  2014370968  990873219
   161619218  6719997
  2062410942  1965300831
  2072442520  938385103
   669324326  1957687455
  1201350414  2134189381
   217290372  1304388089
   726760634  232069103
  2086887656  1784024967
  1345123406  185879429
  1706842790  686104759
  1034648158  268926351
  1445724500  1996600823
  1303450734  1890287253
   763120758  1581912187
  1788401668  1537971261
  1542967608  1842999149
   377964104  1995119937
    87264498  644262155
   224210492  519040373
   692262016  372293591
   502458404  1867793795
   575578512  751306553
   373162704  170423471
  1502626218  152785903
   284546326  287967359
   388031960  1233214425
  1839930048  243652639
   465469190  1747259241
  1488469408  252779515
  2144753340  1992139979
  2010564888  298805387
   917820234  187798339
  1204892922  1454685783
   563347322  50283749
  1303887182  345841727
  1429521892  1668482773
   702286146  1191166889
  1490493310  963750729
   986716484  1522036479
  1107465502  1445768043
  1613852374  1307939505
  1584334086  1565159437
  1325156802  354726127
  1165679412  1618569419
  1192475084  1341169211
    71913214  1569003463
```

There are many ways to put this together, but given your constraint of generating 100 random numbers and then collecting only the even-odd pairs created out of those 100 numbers, the even/odd vectors is a simple to ensure you ended up with only the pairs generated out of the 100. Let me know if that is what you were asking or if you were asking something slightly different.

If you need to enforce only *unique* random numbers, you can fill an `std::unordered_map` from your two vectors.